# Mail form results (no webform)

Tags: emails, forms

I've built a form within a module using form api.
Simply liek this:

```
function input_menu() {
  $items['request'] = array(
    'title' => 'Request',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('input_request'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
}
function input_request($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['make'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Car make'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );
}
```

I have some specific fields that didn't allow me to use webform module.
Now how can I send the results of this form to my mailbox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function input_request($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['make'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Car make'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

return $form; //you need this here
}
```

On order to send it to your mailbox, you will also need a submit button and a submit handler for your form.

Read this, it has good info on how to create, validate, submit, theme drupal forms. http://drupal.org/node/751826

FOr sending email you can use the drupal_mail_send() API or drupal_mail() depending on your Drupal core

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_send/6